# get latest followings photo's and ability to like a page post throw Instagram Graph API

Tags: android, instagram-graph-api

I started to use [Instagram Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api) in my android application, but I can't find any API to get the latest posts of account's followings (just like when you open the Instagram and see the latest posts) also I can't find the API that I could like a photo.
is there any API to do these two things?